# IR confirmation

Tags: infrared, tv

I want a system to send a signal by IR, to turn on a TV. I need to check if the TV is really on by receiving a confirmation.

Is there a way to send the signal, and send an other signal from the TV to confirm it is really on?

Comment: Not without modifying the TV. By default, they don't transmit any IR. (Exception: 3D TVs transmit a signal to synchronize the glasses.) You could rig up something that detects light from the screen (or the power indicator LED, if it has one).

Comment: Where does the confirmation need to be sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a old fashioned CRT TV, then you can look for the 60 Hz (or 50 Hz in some backward parts of the world :-) ) flicker.

Most newer TVs seem to have a LED indicating on/off, sometimes by changing color.  You could tape a LDR or phototransistor over the LED, perhaps with a colored filter if the indicator changes color instead of on/off.  The output from that could then send some modulated IR signal that the remote can pick up.

Another approach is to measure current in one of the wires of the line cord.  This could be done by wrapping it around a ferrite core, with a pickup winding of thinner wire with more turns.  The resulting line frequency signal would then trigger the IR transmitter.

Comment: Thx, this is perfect !

Answer (score 1):

You would need to somehow make a signal when the TV goes on.  Perhaps a monitor for current on the AC power cord would work